# Android - Two types of users in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a simple android application with Firebase. I want to save the users in the real time database without using authentication with email and password. I simply want their name and their role (eg. teacher and student) picked by radiobuttons. Later I want to display all users in a list, but I was wondering how the database should be set up and how to display the right activity based on their role

Should it be:

```
User
 "something"
   username: "name"
   role: "Teacher"
```

or

```
User
  "KA2aslkdajsdlsad"
    username: "name"
    role: "teacher"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely you need to use the second option. You need to use a unique identifier for all those users. For achieving a new unique key (based on time), i recomand you using `push()` method. It's also generated entirely on the client without consultation with the server.

On the other hand i recomand you using [Firebase Anonymous Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. Do you know a way of displaying the right activity based on the picked role?

Comment: User
   -kSFUSDSDeevefeve(Unique key) 
      uid: "KA2aslkdajsdlsad"
      username: "name"
      role: "teacher"

Comment: You're welcome John! This is basically another question. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.

Answer (score 2):

First, make a POJO java object as per your user infos.

```
public class User{
        String username;
        int roleId; // 1 for student, 2 for teacher
        public User(String username, int roleId){
            this.username = username;
            this.roleId = roleId;
        }
    }
```

Now Store your User inside your realtime database like:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child("users")
            .push()
            .setValue(new User("John", 1));
```

If you need to fetch all your users, you can do in this way:

```
final List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child("users")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class); // this is your user
                        userList.add(user); // add to list
                    }
                    // Now may be display all user in listview
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```